# Can Boost.Asio strand.dispatch() block?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I'm experimenting with [Boost.Asio `strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) for a server I'm writing and wanted to clarify a few things.

Let's assume we have `SomeClass` with something like this:

```
void SomeClass::foo()
{
    strand_.dispatch(boost::bind(&SomeClass::bar, this));
}
```

Further, the `strand` has an `io_service` with multiple threads calling `run()`.

In the documentation on [`strand::dispatch()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html) I read it guarantees that handlers posted or dispatched through the strand will not execute concurrently and if this is met the handler **may** execute in this function. What decides if the handler gets to be executed immediately?

In this case with multiple threads, **will dispatch block if multiple io_service threads call `SomeClass::foo` concurrently?** I.e. block for all but the one that gets executed. If so, is the handlers executed in order (the order they called `dispatch()`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, it would be impossible for this guarantee to be met without some possibility of (b)locking.  The code for `dispatch` (in detail/impl/strand_service.hpp from 1.46.1) confirms this.  That's the nice thing about Boost, it's all there for you to see.  There is info on order of handler invocation in the docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html), including a comment that sometimes no ordering guarantee is provided.

```
template <typename Handler>
void strand_service::dispatch(strand_service::implementation_type& impl,
    Handler handler)
{
  // If we are already in the strand then the handler can run immediately.
  if (call_stack<strand_impl>::contains(impl))
  {
    boost::asio::detail::fenced_block b;
    boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(handler, handler);
    return;
  }

  // Allocate and construct an operation to wrap the handler.
  typedef completion_handler<Handler> op;
  typename op::ptr p = { boost::addressof(handler),
    boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
      sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
  p.p = new (p.v) op(handler);

  // If we are running inside the io_service, and no other handler is queued
  // or running, then the handler can run immediately.
  bool can_dispatch = call_stack<io_service_impl>::contains(&io_service_);
  impl->mutex_.lock();
  bool first = (++impl->count_ == 1);
  if (can_dispatch && first)
  {
    // Immediate invocation is allowed.
    impl->mutex_.unlock();

    // Memory must be releaesed before any upcall is made.
    p.reset();

    // Indicate that this strand is executing on the current thread.
    call_stack<strand_impl>::context ctx(impl);

    // Ensure the next handler, if any, is scheduled on block exit.
    on_dispatch_exit on_exit = { &io_service_, impl };
    (void)on_exit;

    boost::asio::detail::fenced_block b;
    boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(handler, handler);
    return;
  }

  // Immediate invocation is not allowed, so enqueue for later.
  impl->queue_.push(p.p);
  impl->mutex_.unlock();
  p.v = p.p = 0;

  // The first handler to be enqueued is responsible for scheduling the
  // strand.
  if (first)
    io_service_.post_immediate_completion(impl);
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Looking at the source you included, it seems that as long as nothing is executing in the strand and the calling thread is part of the io_service the handler will execute in the calling thread. Other cases will enqueue and return leaving the handler to be executed when the strand is free by any thread in the io_service. Is this correct?

Comment: I think that's correct.  A slightly different approach can be gotten by using `post` instead of `dispatch`.

Comment: isn't `post` just the latter case here? It will always enqueue the handler on the strand queue to be picked up whenever nothing is executing in the strand. Or does it also have some other aspect to how things work?